# Binding my autocomplete to my add input functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, autocomplete, event-handling

I've been trying to bind two functions together without success: I want an autocomplete to run on input fields that are added when the user clicks on "add". I can get the two to run separately and have figured out that I should be binding the two functions...but as a noob, I'm almost sure I'm doing it wrong. Any help is appreciated!!

here is the autocomplete code:

```
 var J = jQuery.noConflict();
 J(document).ready(function(){
 J('#professor').autocomplete({source:'autocomplete.php', minLength:1});
 });
```

Here is the add input code:

```
    var J = jQuery.noConflict();
J(document).ready(function(){
J("#addproffield").click(function(){
var input = J("<div class='added-field'><input type='text' name='professor[]' id='professor' size='25' value='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='' class='remove-btn'>Remove field</a></div>");
J("#addprof").append(input);
});
J(".remove-btn").live('click',function() {
J(this).parent().remove();
});
});
```

here is my failed attempt to bind the two:

```
   var J = jQuery.noConflict();
J(document).ready(function(){
J("#addproffield").click(function(){
var input = J("<div class='added-field'><input type='text' name='professor[]' id='professor' size='25' value='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='' class='remove-btn'>Remove field</a></div>");
J("#addprof").append(input);
input.professor({
     source:'autocomplete.php', minLength:1
    });
});
J(".remove-btn").live('click',function() {
J(this).parent().remove();
});
    });
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your quick responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding the autocmplete (`.professor`?) to the `<div>` instead of the `<input>` in your attempt, so it just needs a little adjustment to actually be the `<input>` element via [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), like this:

```
J(document).ready(function(){
    J("#addproffield").click(function(){
    var div = J("<div class='added-field'><input type='text' name='professor[]' size='25' value='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='' class='remove-btn'>Remove field</a></div>");
    J("#addprof").append(div);

    div.find("input").autocomplete({
        source:'autocomplete.php', minLength:1
    });
});
```

Note the html changes above, the `id` need not be there now and shouldn't be, since it's invalid to use the same ID multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The `live` function in jQuery works great for applying specific event handlers to selected elements dynamically as the DOM changes, but there isn't (as far as I know) a method for executing/calling functions on selected elements which **set up** event handlers (like the `autocomplete` function in this question)...

So, you'll need to do something like this:

```
var J = jQuery.noConflict();

J(document).ready(function(){
    J("#addproffield").click(function(){
        var input = J("<div class='added-field'><input type='text' name='professor[]' size='25' value='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='' class='remove-btn'>Remove field</a></div>");
        J("#addprof").append(input);

        //Next line is inefficient and requires the extra class attribute
        //J(".professor").unbind().autocomplete({source:'autocomplete.php', minLength:1});

        //This is better:
        input.find("input").autocomplete({source:'autocomplete.php', minLength:1});
    });

    J(".remove-btn").live('click',function() {
        J(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

I've added the class `professor` to each of the `input` elements because you can't have valid HTML with duplicated IDs (and jQuery doesn't handle duplicated IDs).

I've also changed the `input.professor...` line so that events (onclick, mouseover etc) are removed from all `input`s with `class="professor"` and then the autocomplete function is applied (again) to all of the elements selected.

You might be able to do the following but I haven't tried:

```
var input = J("<div class='added-field'><input type='text' name='professor[]' id='professor' class='professor' size='25' value='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='' class='remove-btn'>Remove field</a></div>").autocomplete({source:'autocomplete.php', minLength:1});
J("#addprof").append(input);
```

**EDIT:** took Nick's advice/answer and updated code above and removed the `id` and `class` attributes

Comment: There's no need to un/re-bind *every* autocomplete element, it'd be much more efficient to *only* hook up autocomplete to *only* the one being added.

Comment: That's a very good point - and is why your answer is better than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

You're close, instead of `input.professor`, try `input.find("#professor").autocomplete` in your code above.

The find method basically searches for a selector (id in this case) within the element.

Comment: While this does work (and it's a travesty jquery allows it to be honest), it totally ignores the issue of invalid HTML from duplicate ID selectors...best to resolve that as well.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked the issue of this occurring more than once. All I had in mind was getting a quick fix. I posted from a mobile.